# React + Flask | Server/Client Setup on Replit

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, replit

I was wondering if there was a way to have a server/client setup on Replit with React and Flask. I know that this is possible by running the client and server separately from the shell. However, this is inconvenient as you must run both apps on 0.0.0.0, which means that there may be issues. A second inconvenience is not being able to configure the .replit file to run both.

Tried changing the .replit file
Tried using shell commands
Changed python to node the node to python twice to see if it would work but it didnt

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: normally on local computer you could use `subprocess.run()` in python to start one script and run two processes at the same time. But Replit may run code in specials containers which has only Python or only other framework - so they can't run in one container.